# Upgrade apt bitcoin-core package

Tags: bitcoin-core

I originally set up my bitcoin-core node on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial using `apt`.

The `ppa:/bitcoin/bitcoin` package repository that I used isn't maintained beyond version 0.15.0, so I need a different way to upgrade to the latest version.

Options seem to be to use either `snap` or compile from source.

Would appreciate any advise on options. I have full blockchain and I don't want to do anything stupid like deleting it.

Right now, everything is in `/root/.bitcoin`. Ideally, I'd prefer to switch to source compiling, so as not to run into this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

So, I completed this without issue by compiling from source.

The `apt` package binaries were installed in `/usr/bin`. When compiling from source I used the `./configure --prefix=` option to install the updated binaries in a different location.

All of my configuration and block data remained in `/root/.bitcoin`. By default, the code looks for `bitcoin.conf` in `~/.bitcoin` so once I executed the new binaries it found the configuration as required.

I haven't removed the `apt` package, but I did move the older version binaries from `/usr/bin` and have added the new location to `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to update your Bitcoin core wallet you can just download the new version and open the new bitcoin-qt file.